# building pidgin-otr-4.0.0 on CentOS 7: can't find pidgin and purple

Tags: centos, compiling, configure

I have built pidgin from source on CentOS 7. This is because there is no package available yet. This went well, however, `pidgin-otr-4.0.0` cannot find the headers for `pidgin` and `purple`.

They reside in `/usr/local/include`, and I can't work out what the configure script wants with its suggestion:

```
checking for EXTRA... configure: error: Package requirements (glib-2.0 >= 2.6 gtk+-2.0 >= 2.6 pidgin >= 2.0 purple >= 2.0) were not met:

No package 'pidgin' found
No package 'purple' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables EXTRA_CFLAGS
and EXTRA_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I tried a variety of `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` options such as `/usr/local` and `/usr/local/include`, as well as `EXTRA_LIBS`. I am not sure what to do at this point.

I just need to specify somehow that `pidgin` and `purple` reside in `/usr/local/include`.

Comment: I found the answer: `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig ./configure`

Comment: If you found an answer, please add it as a answer. Thanks.

Comment: I'm new and I had not met the timeout to answer at the time of comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer after having a second look at the `pkg-config` manual, and better understanding the purpose of those environment variables. I also noticed I could do a Google  search for `pidgin pkg-config`. I was then able to find the solution.

This allows configure to find the required libraries with pkg-config...

```
$ PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig ./configure
```

This allowed it to find `pidgin` and `purple`.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is for CentOS, but since it was the first result I got when looking for Ubuntu, here are some Ubuntu 16.04 helpers.

I was missing `pidgin, purple, gtk+-2.0`

I needed to 
`sudo apt install libgtk2.0-dev pidgin-dev libpurple-dev libgcrypt20-dev`

Comment: Useful for me, but not the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Same error happened to me with [pidgin-libnotify](https://github.com/yorikvanhavre/pidgin-libnotify) on RHEL 7.4.

This has resolved it for me:

```
sudo -i
yum install libnotify-devel
yum install libpurple-devel
yum install pidgin-devel
yum install gtk2-devel
```

<s>env PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib64/pkgconfig ./configure</s>

(Do not use pkgconfig from *lib64* - Although configuration will pass, it will fail later during compilation - with an unsigned int error).

```
./configure
make
make install
```

Now copy the **generated plugin.so** (in my case src/pidgin-libnotify.so) to your user **.purple/plugins** directory.